# SAS sampling to return groups of transaction records

Tags: sas, sampling

I have a large dataset from which I want to sample a set of date/transactionIDs
Each transaction ID relates to multiple rows in the data - say 1-20 rows per ID & I'd like to return all of these records within the date/transactionID sampled

Due to the size of the data I'd rather avoid sampling the transaction ID and joining back to pick up all of the records

Comment: You will need two steps here one way or another: get the IDs and then get the corresponding rows of data.  You don't need to use the whole large dataset to obtain the IDs (just use KEEP= to grab the ID column).  Are you familiar with hash or index merges in SAS?  Those will probably be the fastest ways to retrieve those other rows.  I've worked with similar problems for years (instead of transaction IDs I had person IDs).

Comment: Do you have `Proc SURVEYSELECT`? How large is large ?

Comment: Richard large is billions, and moderately wide, incl text fields. I'm already using hash merges to join some of the system keys as @AlexK mentions, so I may have to default onto that. It'll also let me more options in the sampling (stratified would let me be more explicit about coverage)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataset is already sorted by (or indexed on) ID + date, it is possible to do some simple random sampling of this type in 1 data step, e.g. using a DOW-loop:

```
data want;
  call streaminit(0);
  sample_rate = 0.05;
  flag = rand('uniform') < sample_rate;
  do until(last.date);
    set have;
    by ID date;
    if flag then output;
  end;
  drop flag sample_rate;
run;
```

Comment: You want `until(last.id)` to output all rows in the flagged group.

Comment: My understanding is that the asker is interested in combinations of id and date.